# Full width image containing the image ratio is not stretched in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to add an image that is always 100% width but height is stretched containing the ratio of the image.

I'm adding the image in container:

```
 <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
     <Image style={styles.image} source={require('../../assets/images/image.png')}/>
 </View>
```

And changing the resize mode to 'contain':

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    imageContainer: {
        flex: 1,
    },

    image: {
        width: '100%',
        resizeMode: 'contain',
        backgroundColor: 'red',
    }
}
```

[image]

Image background shows that the image is 100% width (red background) but the source is not stretched. What is the proper way to achieve the result below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';

const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

.............
.............

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    image: {
        ....
        width: deviceWidth,
        resizeMode: 'stretch',
        .....
    }
}
```

Comment: I now get what you mean. Can you try `resizeMode: 'stretch'` . And if does not work, you might have to manually add `marginRight: -20` and `marginLeft: -20` to your image container.

Comment: If I stretch the image, the bottom part of it is cut.

Comment: Ohh, I skipped the 'stretch' part. It works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can start by importing this library:

```
import Dimensions from 'react-native';
```

Then you define globally:

```
const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const height = Dimensions.get('window').height;
```

The proper way to write your code is:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    imageContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        height: height,
    },

    image: {
        width: width,
        resizeMode: 'contain',
        backgroundColor: 'red',
    }
}
```

Comment: As you see the image width is already full width (red background). So it doesn't change anything.